# TexMaker: second "quick build" does not produce correct formulas

Tags: miktex, texmaker

When "quick building" the following simple file

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
$a+b=c$
\end{document}
```

in the generated PDF I correctly get "a+b=c".
When "quick building" a second time without leaving TexMaker, I get only " + = ", i.e. letters a, b, c have vanished. Opening the PDF with acrobat gives an error message that says that the embedded fonts AUUZAN+CMMI10 could not be extracted.

When adding a line
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
the result of the second "quick build" is "a b c", i.e now the + and = have vanished, and the acrobat error reports fonts RFLZJB+CMR10 missing.

Adding other packages like `amsmath` or others does not change things.

When I close and re-open TexMaker before the second "quick build", the PDF is produced with the correct formula, but another "quick build" gives the same problem.

What can I do?

(using TexMaker 4.4.1 + MikTex 2.9, both installed today, no configuration changes; "quick build" set to first option "PdfLatex + View PDF")

Comment: Can you open a new document in `notepad` (or what is available on your OS) and write per hand (no copy/pasting) the same document. Save as lutz.tex and open it with TeXmaker. Does the same monkey business occur?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: The tex-files were stored on a DropBox-folder under encryption by BoxCryptor, and that thing seems to hold open or otherwise block some file resources; on DropBox without BoxCryptor, as well as on the local filesystem, everything is fine.

So this issue is solved.